# Consumir web service con PHP

Tags: php, webservice

Estoy tratando de consumir un WS con PHP por medio de petición POST, pero al momento de probar si funciona el WS, solo me muestra string(297) " ".

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$url = "https://cotizaciones.bcu.gub.uy/wscotizaciones/servlet/awsbcucotizaciones";

$data=array("Moneda"=>"0", "FechaDesde"=>"2022-03-01","FechaHasta"=>"2022-03-31","Grupo"=>"0");
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if(!$resp){
    return false;
}else{
    $json=json_decode($resp); 
    echo "<pre>"; 
    var_dump($resp);
}
?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136132/discussion-on-question-by-stephirm-consumir-web-service-con-php).

Answer (score 1):

Es evidente que estás intentando acceder a un Web Service basado en Soap. Por tanto, lo mejor es escribir una petición usando [la clase `SoapClient`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php) de PHP.

La forma de configurar la petición es algo distinta, por ejemplo, la URL se escribiría así: `https://cotizaciones.bcu.gub.uy/wscotizaciones/servlet/awsbcucotizaciones?wsdl`.

Tendrías también que configurar el contexto (si fuera preciso) y pasar los parámetros de otro modo ([para el código sugerido me he inspirado en este gist](https://gist.github.com/MaskeZen/5cc768ae34c998d3970785d245378dea)), si tienes alguna duda lo mejor es leer la documentación ofrecida por el WS, o contactar con ellos si esto es posible. Por ejemplo, en el gist, el parámetro para la `Moneda` se pasaría de este modo: `'Moneda'     => ['item' => 0]`. Si lo pasas como lo tienes en tu pregunta la petición falla. Dado que no conozco ese WS ni sé cómo funciona, lo mejor es que te informes al respecto sobre la forma adecuada de consultarlo.

Tu petición quedaría así más o menos:

```
$url = "https://cotizaciones.bcu.gub.uy/wscotizaciones/servlet/awsbcucotizaciones?wsdl";
$context = [
    "ssl" => [
      "verify_peer"      => FALSE,
      "verify_peer_name" => FALSE,
      'crypto_method'    => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
    ]
];

$options = [
    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($context)
];

$params = [
    'Entrada' => [
      'FechaDesde' => '2022-03-01',
      'FechaHasta' => '2022-03-31',
      'Grupo'      => 0,
      'Moneda'     => ['item' => 0]
    ]
];

$client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
$response = $client->Execute($params);
var_dump($response);
```

#### Salida

Tendrás un objeto completo con los datos pedidos. Considera que las respuesta de un WS puede mapearse a clases que ya tengas y que te ayudan a leer los datos. No sé cual sea tu contexto, pero este sería ya otro asunto.

Aquí una parte de la respuesta, que puedes leer usando las clases o según la estructura de la misma:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["Salida"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["respuestastatus"]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
      ["status"]=>
      int(1)
      ["codigoerror"]=>
      int(0)
      ["mensaje"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["datoscotizaciones"]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
      ["datoscotizaciones.dato"]=>
      array(916) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#6 (9) {
          ["Fecha"]=>
          string(10) "2022-03-01"
          ["Moneda"]=>
          int(9203)
          ["Nombre"]=>
          string(20) "Tasa Med. de Mercado"
          ["CodigoISO"]=>
          string(3) "N/A"
          ["Emisor"]=>
          string(7) "URUGUAY"
          ["TCC"]=>
          float(7.02)
          ["TCV"]=>
          float(7.02)
          ["ArbAct"]=>
          float(0)
          ["FormaArbitrar"]=>
          int(9)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#7 (9) {
          ["Fecha"]=>
          string(10) "2022-03-01"
          ["Moneda"]=>
          int(9700)
          ["Nombre"]=>
          string(18) "UNIDAD PREVISIONAL"
          ["CodigoISO"]=>
          string(2) "UP"
          ["Emisor"]=>
          string(7) "URUGUAY"
          ["TCC"]=>
          float(1.28894)
          ["TCV"]=>
          float(1.28894)
          ["ArbAct"]=>
          float(0.030304)
          ["FormaArbitrar"]=>
          int(1)
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#8 (9) {
          ["Fecha"]=>
          string(10) "2022-03-02"
          ["Moneda"]=>
          int(2)
          ["Nombre"]=>
          string(16) "DER.ESP. DE GIRO"
          ["CodigoISO"]=>
          string(3) "SDR"
          ["Emisor"]=>
          string(6) "F.M.I."
          ["TCC"]=>
          float(59.39777)
          ["TCV"]=>
          float(59.39777)
          ["ArbAct"]=>
          float(1.39056)
          ["FormaArbitrar"]=>
          int(1)
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#9 (9) {
          ["Fecha"]=>
          string(10) "2022-03-02"
          ["Moneda"]=>
          int(105)
          ["Nombre"]=>
          string(16) "DOL. AUSTRALIANO"
          ["CodigoISO"]=>
          string(3) "AUD"
          ["Emisor"]=>
          string(9) "AUSTRALIA"
          ["TCC"]=>
          float(31.179814)
          ["TCV"]=>
          float(31.179814)
          ["ArbAct"]=>
          float(0.72995)
          ["FormaArbitrar"]=>
          int(1)
        }

        ... etc
```